# Block URL access when specific word exists

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

I'm looking to configure annotations in ingress to block certain words
For example if I access the endpoint(same as `host` in ingress) using `https://my-endpoint?blocked-word` , URL should either be re-written to `https://my-endpoint` or user should get 400 response code back

To achieve this I need to monitor the URL for the `blocked-word`. Can I achieve the above scenarios configuring just the annotations in ingress?

**EDIT:**
`server-snippet` with `location` cannot be used as it's added to blocklist for our nginx-controller